# How to set defalulValue or stored value in react (browser extention)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, antd, browser-extension

With little experience with react, I am working on a browser extension (chrome and firefox) with reactJS and using but after users sign-in it even though the UI is set to my intended default value but the functionality is not being implemented. However, after a user selects an option then the functionality works.

Here is my state:

```
... 
 state {
  mode: 'mode-1'
 }
...
```

my functions:

```
  onChange = e => {
   let newMode = e.target.value

   this.setState({
     mode: newMode
    })
    this.handleChanges(newMode)
 };

  handleChanges=(setMode)=> {
   chrome.storage.local.set({ 'mode': setMode })
 }
  getStoredMode= () => {
   chrome.storage.local.get(['mode'], (result) => {
   ...
  }
 }
  componentDidMount () {
   this.getStoredMode()
  }
```

My radio components (Ant-design):

```
<RadioGroup onChange={this.onChange} className="radio__group" value={this.state.mode}>

<Radio defaultChecked={true} className="radio__group-text" value='mode-1'>
    <span className='radio__group-span'>mode-1</span>
</Radio>

<Radio className="radio__group-text" value='mode-2'>
    <span className="radio__group-span">mode-2</span>
</Radio>

<Radio className="radio__group-text" value='mode-3'>
    <span className="radio__group-span">mode-3</span>
</Radio>

</RadioGroup>
```

Any suggestions on making this radio button work will be well appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: can you provide online working code snippet?

Comment: I tried recreating the code here but because it is a browser extension I have to use the chrome.storage API : https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cloud-bcl8p

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code sandbox. You should add a check if there is nothing in the chrome storage, then get a default value from `state`.

```
 storedModeInLocalStorage = () => {
     chrome.storage.local.get(['mode'], function(result) {
        let value = result.mode || this.state.mode;
        console.log('Value currently is ' + value );
     });

  };
```